# Docker compose can't find entry point, but docker run can?

Tags: c++, docker, docker-compose

I'm getting this error when trying to use my compose up:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./Nssams": stat ./Nssams: no such file or directory: unknown
```

This is my compose file

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  eventlogger:
    container_name: nssams-eventlogger_
    image: nssams-eventlogger
    environment: 
      - MQTT_HOST=mqtt
    depends_on:
      - mqtt
    command: python run.py
  
  mqtt:
      container_name: nssams-mqtt_
      image: eclipse-mosquitto:1.6.15
      ports: 
        - 1883:1883

  ebcmos:
    image: nssams-ebcmos
    container_name: ebcmos
    networks:
      - default
    volumes:
      - ./capture/ebcmos:/app/capture:wo
      - ./logs/ebcmos:/app/
      - /dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyUSB0
      - ./xmp/ebcmos:/app/xmp/ebcmos
    environment:
      - CAMERA_NAME=ebcmos
    privileged: true
    depends_on:
      - mqtt
      - eventlogger

networks:
    default:
        driver: bridge
        name: nssams_bridge
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS builder

# Install dependencies for building mqtt client from source.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install build-essential git gcc make cmake cmake-gui cmake-curses-gui doxygen

# removed a bunch of irrelevant installs for stack overflow

RUN mkdir -p /app/build \
    && cd build \
    && cmake .. \
    && cmake --build .

# Production Image
FROM debian:latest AS prod
LABEL maintainer=redacted

WORKDIR /app
 
# Copy NSSAMS executable to prod image. 
COPY --from=builder /app/build/Nssams .

CMD [ "./Nssams" ]
```

but if I run the below command:

```
docker run -it --privileged --volume {volume} {image_name} bash
```

I can exec it, and see my Nssams executable in /app. I then just go ./Nssams in a shell, and the application starts up.

Why can't docker compose do the same?

Comment: The second `volumes:` line mounts `./logs/ebcmos` over all of `/app/`, hiding the binary.  Do you mean to mount this over a subdirectory?

Comment: Ahhh yep, that was it... that should have been ./logs/ebcmos:/app/logs, not just /app